# Mapping $\mathbb{Z}$ onto $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinitesimals

There is a problem that calls for the mapping the set of all the positive integers to the set of all positive rational numbers in order to prove they have the same cardinality. I know more the common answer of mapping it this way:

Map $\mathbb{Q}$ like a table of ℤ x ℤ:

\begin{array}{rl}
  &  &1    &2  &3   &4   &5 \\
\\   
 1 & &1/1  &2/1 &3/1 &4/1 &5/1  \\
2 & &1/2  &2/2 &3/2 &4/2 &5/2 \\
\end{array}

Then you show the cardinality of that as in {1/1,2/1,3/1,4/1,/5/1,1/2/3/2 ... } is the same as the carnality of {1,2,3,4,5,6}

However, my first idea was much different. Now, I have not yet taken very high level courses, this is my intro to set theory. But why couldn't I do something like this:

The first element in the set $\mathbb{Q}$ is:

ε, where ε is an infinitesimal approaching 0. 
 the second element of $\mathbb{Q}$ is  ε, where  ε is an infinitesimal approaching the first member, and so forth.

so

$$S(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} ε_i$$

where n ∈ $\mathbb{Z}$

This was the essence of my idea. I am sure it is probably way of base. But could someone explain why?

**EDIT:**

I think I understand where I was going wrong. Defining the infinitesimal here is non standard, and I can't think of it like a limit. The sum I use is also not correct.

$$S = \{\varepsilon_i : i \in \mathbb Z\}$$

is a far better way to represent what I am trying to say.

Then my question boils down to asking if $$S = \{\varepsilon_i : i \in \mathbb Z\}$$ is equal to the set of the positive rational numbers. In which case, no. Because the infinitesimal cant be used in this way.

@graydad mentioned another cool / non-standard way to map $\mathbb{Z}$ onto $\mathbb{Q}$

Let $f:\Bbb{Q}^+ \to \left\{2^n3^m :n,m \in \Bbb{Z}^+\right\}$ be defined by $f(n/m) = 2^n3^m$ where $n/m$ is in lowest reduced form. Then by the F.T. of Arithmetic we know $2^n3^m \neq 2^l3^p$ whenever $n/m \neq l/p$. You can show $f$ is a bijection and that the set $\left\{2^n3^m :n,m \in \Bbb{Z}^+\right\}$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb{Z}$.

That is pretty interesting!

Comment: Well, for starters, how are you differentiating between your two infinitesimal $\varepsilon$'s? If I asked you for the integer that mapped to $\frac{5765457}{124563455}$, would you know how to find it? More importantly, does your method guarantee that an integer will map to $\frac{5765457}{124563455}$?

Comment: What is the smallest or first number in $\Bbb Q$?  If I divide it by $2$, what then? Is there a rational number between the "first" and "second" numbers?

Comment: My point with the ε was to denote the smallest possible number @ @abiessu approaching 0. It is essentially a limit. There are some formulas to denote that number. But the theory I had rejects that it could be divided by to because ε is as small as it gets. I get that infinitesimals aren't accepted as mathematically rigorous sometimes and maybe this is one of those times.

Comment: @graydad that is a valid point. You couldn't find the integer mapped, because the rigor for the infinitesimal isn't there.

Comment: Infinitesimals can be used rigorously, but you have to use a non-standard number system. The problem is that they aren't even real numbers, let alone rational! Also, they aren't "approaching" anything, just as the number $5$ isn't approaching anything. The concept of infinitesimals is distinct from that of limits.

Comment: Right, thanks for that. That makes sense! @Théophile

Comment: @GeraldAnderson Correct, as stated it will not work. Good for you for trying to prove results on your own though! Since you're interested in showing equality of $|\Bbb{Z}^+|$ and $|\Bbb{Q}^+|$ in non-stardard ways, what do you think of this one?

Let $f:\Bbb{Q}^+ \to \left\{2^n3^m :n,m \in \Bbb{Z}^+\right\}$ be defined by $f(n/m) = 2^n3^m$ where $n/m$ is in lowest reduced form. Then by the F.T. of Arithmetic we know $2^n3^m \neq 2^l3^p$ whenever $n/m \neq l/p$. You can show $f$ is a bijection and that the set $\left\{2^n3^m :n,m \in \Bbb{Z}^+\right\}$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: That is awesome @graydad! I added it to my post as a cool way (That also actually works haha ;) )!

Comment: @GeraldAnderson I am flattered! There may be a few kinks to work out with how I stated the idea, but hopefully it's clear what I'm getting at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting idea, but there are several major problems here. For one, the approach lacks rigour: what exactly do you mean for $\varepsilon$ to be an "infinitesimal approaching zero"? What is this thing? Does it have a fixed value, or is it moving around?

Just as importantly, if $\varepsilon$ is "infinitesimal" or "approaching zero", then it certainly doesn't sound like an element of $\mathbb Q$.

Third, what is $S(n)$? You are defining it to be the *sum* of the $\varepsilon_n$, but perhaps you want it to be a *set* of these objects:
$$S = \{\varepsilon_i : i \in \mathbb Z\}$$

Also, even if this method with infinitesimals were possible, you haven't proved in any way that it leads to a *countable* set. How do you know you won't need uncountably many of these infinitesimals?

Comment: I define  the ε as the infinitesimal in an ordered field that is an element e>0e>0 such that e<1ne<1n for all n∈ℕ. I totally agree with you that it lacks rigor. Your set definition is a lot better than what I was thinking.

Comment: @GeraldAnderson Okay, it's good that you had a definition in mind. Note that by this definition, an infinitesimal cannot be rational. In fact, if you start piling them up as you described above, you would already need infinitely many of them before reaching even the tiniest rational number!

Comment: Is there a definition of an infinitesimal that is rational?

Comment: @GeraldAnderson No, the only definition that I am aware of is for a non-standard number system. Infinitesimals aren't even real numbers, because by definition they are smaller than every real.